# Can't configure easy-rsa as vars file didn't exist

Tags: openvpn

I'm trying to set up open vpn latest version on CentOS 7 following this tutorial
https://www.hugeserver.com/kb/how-to-config-openvpn-linux-server/

The problem was there was no "vars" file to edit.

I checked every folder in easy-rsa including 3, 3.0, 3.0.3 and didn't find any "vars" file inside them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like in three this stuff changed. Tested this out and got it to work with openvpn so I believe what your looking for is...

```
 ./easyrsa init-pki
 ./easyrsa build-ca
 ./easyrsa gen-req server nopass
 ./easyrsa sign-req server server
  openssl dhparam -out dh2048.pem 2048
```

Some more reference on this.... 
https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/EasyRSA3-OpenVPN-Howto

Answer (score 0):

use this documentation and you can get var files 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-7

Comment: Welcome to SO. Link-only answers are discouraged because it takes longer to evaluate the information and if the link is changed or dies your answer may become useless.